# Vue computed functionality won't compile for syntax errors

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a computed element in my Vue code that won't compile because of an unexpected token on line 3/4  around `return this.dataEvents
          .filter(dataEvent => !this.filters.title`

It seems like logically this should be correct, but it simply won't build for syntax and token errors.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
computed: {
  filtered() {
    return this.dataEvents
      .filter(dataEvent => !this.filters.title || dataEvent.title === this.filters.title),
      .filter(dataEvent => !this.filters.resource || dataEvent.resource === this.filters.resource),
      .filter(dataEvent => !this.filters.location || dataEvent.location === this.filters.location),
      .filter(dataEvent => !this.filters.status || dataEvent.status === this.filters.status);
  },

  titles() {
    return this.dataEvents.map(dataEvent => dataEvent.title)
      .filter((title, index, self) => self.indexOf(title) === index);
  },

  resources() {
    return this.dataEvents
      .map(dataEvent => dataEvent.resource)
      .filter((resource, index, self) => self.indexOf(resource) === index);
  },

  locations() {
    return this.dataEvents
      .map(dataEvent => dataEvent.location)
      .filter((location, index, self) => self.indexOf(location) === index);
  },

  statuses() {
    return this.dataEvents
      .map(dataEvent => dataEvent.status)
      .filter((status, index, self) => self.indexOf(status) === index);
  },
},
```

Comment: It should not add comma after `filter`

Comment: ah good call! That fixed it, thanks!